# meta robots for logged in vs. not logged in users

Tags: seo, authentication, meta-robots

On a site I'm working on, The homepage has generic content for visitors who aren't logged in. When a user is logged in, the content shown is personalized to them and could even be considered private.

So when a user is not logged in:

URL: `http://example.com`

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

When a user is logged in:

URL: `http://example.com`

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

Since both URLs are the same, are there any SEO concerns since the robots directives are different? Is it better to send the user to a different URL for their personalized homepage, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no bot will ever reach a 'logged' page, as [i think] it can only be obtained filling the login form; thing that no robot [AFAIK] can do today

Comment: what about browsers... Chrome uses browsing data to help rank search results and might use the meta robots tag?

Comment: I don't think, even if chrome uses data, it is for tailoring your results; other people's results won't be affected.